# Performing between-row comparisons of dates in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of several thousand ICU patients covering several years. Some patients (each with a unique identifier, ID) have had multiple ICU admissions. Each row covers a single ICU admission, and therefore an individual patient may have multiple rows of data.

For each patient, I want to determine whether their ICU admission was:

- A readmission during the same hospital stay. This could be identified by an icu_adm time occurring prior to their previous hosp_dis time, or by multiple rows with the same hosp_dis time.
- A transfer to a different ICU for management of the same illness. I am defining this as an icu_adm time occurring within 24 hours of their previous hosp_dis time. These patients icu_dis time and hosp_dis time should be the same, as their hospital discharge occured from ICU.
- A new admission of the same patient

I am able to use lubridate to compare times without difficulty, but I am stuck on how to do the between-row comparisons, especially for patients with multiple ICU admissions (who have new admissions, readmissions, and transfers all in the time period of interest).

Some example data:

```
ID  site icu_adm                icu_dis             hosp_adm            hosp_dis
1   A    2016-02-02 15:38:00    2016-02-06 14:25:00 2016-02-02 15:17:00 2016-02-06 14:25:00
1   B    2016-02-06 16:17:00    2016-02-16 14:16:00 2016-02-06 16:16:00 2016-03-16 17:50:00
2   C    2009-08-09 14:27:00    2009-08-10 15:06:00 2009-08-03 02:51:00 2009-09-02 00:00:00
3   C    2009-08-18 20:32:00    2009-08-27 15:10:00 2009-08-03 02:51:00 2009-09-02 00:00:00
3   A    2010-02-20 21:00:00    2010-03-03 13:00:00 2010-02-18 03:00:00 2010-03-18 15:21:00
3   B    2010-05-05 17:00:00    2010-05-08 09:13:00 2010-05-03 11:21:00 2010-05-20 17:18:00
```

Desired output would be:

```
ID  …   readmission transferred new_adm
1       0           0           1
1       0           1           0
2       0           0           1
2       1           0           0
3       0           0           1
3       0           0           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this will work with all of your data, but thought this might be helpful.

Using `tidyverse` (or `dplyr` package in this case), you can start by grouping by `ID` to look at transfers. Based on your definition, if your `icu_adm` time is less than 24 hours of the previous row's discharge time (`hosp_dis`), then it is considered an ICU transfer. You can use `lag` to compare with previous row, assume dates/times are in chronological order (if not, you can use `arrange` to order).

Next, you can group by `ID`, `hosp_adm`, and `hosp_dis`. This will help look at readmissions. After grouping, all rows of data after the first row (for the *same* hospital admission) will be considered ICU readmissions.

Then, everything left that is not a transfer or readmission could be considered a new ICU admission.

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(transfer = ifelse(abs(difftime(icu_adm, lag(hosp_dis, default = first(hosp_dis)), units = "hours")) < 24, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(ID, hosp_adm, hosp_dis) %>%
  mutate(readmission = ifelse(row_number() > 1, 1, 0),
         new_adm = ifelse(transfer != 1 & readmission != 1, 1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
     ID site  icu_adm             icu_dis             hosp_adm            hosp_dis            transfer readmission new_adm
  <int> <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 A     2016-02-02 15:38:00 2016-02-06 14:25:00 2016-02-02 15:17:00 2016-02-06 14:25:00        0           0       1
2     1 B     2016-02-06 16:17:00 2016-02-16 14:16:00 2016-02-06 16:16:00 2016-03-16 17:50:00        1           0       0
3     2 C     2009-08-09 14:27:00 2009-08-10 15:06:00 2009-08-03 02:51:00 2009-09-02 00:00:00        0           0       1
4     2 C     2009-08-18 20:32:00 2009-08-27 15:10:00 2009-08-03 02:51:00 2009-09-02 00:00:00        0           1       0
5     3 A     2010-02-20 21:00:00 2010-03-03 13:00:00 2010-02-18 03:00:00 2010-03-18 15:21:00        0           0       1
6     3 B     2010-05-05 17:00:00 2010-05-08 09:13:00 2010-05-03 11:21:00 2010-05-20 17:18:00        0           0       1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), site = c("A", 
"B", "C", "C", "A", "B"), icu_adm = structure(c(1454427480, 1454775420, 
1249828020, 1250627520, 1266699600, 1273078800), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), icu_dis = structure(c(1454768700, 1455632160, 1249916760, 
1251385800, 1267621200, 1273309980), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), hosp_adm = structure(c(1454426220, 1454775360, 1249267860, 
1249267860, 1266462000, 1272885660), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), hosp_dis = structure(c(1454768700, 1458150600, 1251849600, 
1251849600, 1268925660, 1274375880), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I had to alter this a bit (mostly to get other useful variables out of the process) but `group_by` and `lag` were critical.