# comparing dates between rows with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to compare dates between rows and apply a logic to them.  I used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183809/performing-between-row-comparisons-of-dates-in-r) as a starting point but I'm getting an error for the actual date comparison.

What I'm trying to determine is

1. the time in days between subsequent purchases, and
2. if the time is 60 days or greater, and
3. what was the current and previous purchase

A sample is:

```
mydata <- data.frame(store=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
                     PurchaseDate =c('2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01',    '2023-04-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-06-01'), 
                 sales=c("apples", "bananas", "cherries", "bananas", "cherries", "cherries", "bananas", "bananas"))

mydata$PurchaseDate <- as.Date(mydata$PurchaseDate)


mydata %>%
  group_by(store) |> arrange((PurchaseDate), .by_group = TRUE)
```

And what I wanted to return was something like this to show the days between subsequent purchases, if it was 60 days or more, and what the previous purchase was.  Ultimately I would compare the sale to LastSale.

```
store  PurchaseDate  sales      LastPurchase    over60   LastSale
A      2023-01-01   apples        0             0          NA
A      2023-02-01   cherries     32             0          apples
A      2023-04-02   cherries     61             1          cherries
A      2023-05-01   bananas      31             0          cherries
B      2023-01-01   bananas      0              0          NA
B      2023-03-02   bananas      61             1          bananas
B      2023-04-01   cherries     31             0          bananas
B      2023-06-01   bananas      62             1          cherries
```

And I tried this, but now I know that the difftime is wrong here, but what I want is the difference between adjacent rows.

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(store) |> arrange((PurchaseDate), .by_group = TRUE) |>
  mutate(over60 = ifelse(abs(difftime(PurchaseDate, lag(sales, default =first(PurchaseDate)), units = "days")) < 60, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Your `sales` is a character column describing fruits (in your sample data), so `difftime()` cant calculate the differences between a time and fruit (as you have in your current code). Could you edit your question to describe in more detail what you are tying to do and what the logic is? How is `Days` calculated? (that's not shown at all in your current code). You also have `over60` in your code but `over30` in your desired output. If you clean this question up a bit and add more details, you'll be likely to get better, faster help. Just trying to get you the help you need - good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I made those changes.  I'm not sure how to fix the difftime to show adjacent rows so I just used words there.

Comment: Are you sure on the date range computation, i.e. "2023-02-01 - 2023-01-01" is 31 and not 30. Also, please clarify on `Over60`.

Comment: To be precise, looking at your desired output, why is `Over60` set to 1 if the corresponding day column shows 60?

Comment: @Friede  I did calculate the days incorrectly - I've made that adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata |>
  group_by(store) |> 
  arrange((PurchaseDate), .by_group = TRUE) |>
  mutate(Day = as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(PurchaseDate), lag(as.Date(PurchaseDate)), units = "days")), 
         Over60 = ifelse(Day > 60L, 1L, 0L), 
         LastSale = lag(sales))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
# Groups:   store [2]
  store PurchaseDate sales      Day Over60 LastSale
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <dbl>  <int> <chr>   
1 A     2023-01-01   apples      NA     NA NA      
2 A     2023-02-01   cherries    31      0 apples  
3 A     2023-04-01   cherries    59      0 cherries
4 A     2023-05-01   bananas     30      0 cherries
5 B     2023-01-01   bananas     NA     NA NA      
6 B     2023-03-01   bananas     59      0 bananas 
7 B     2023-04-01   cherries    31      0 bananas 
8 B     2023-06-01   bananas     61      1 cherries
```

Having `NA` in the `Day` column could offer potential advantages. Clearly, as always it depends on the task. See `?lag` for clarification. The `lag`-function from `{dplyr}` is used, `R base` provides another `lag`-function which does not have a `default=`-argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code creates the three specific columns in your request. The diff function in base r calculates the difference between consecutive PurchaseDate values. It begins with 0 for the first PurchaseDate as there is no previous PurchaseDate to compare to.

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(store)  |> 
  arrange((PurchaseDate), .by_group = TRUE)  |> 
  mutate(LastPurchase = c(0, diff(PurchaseDate)),
  over60 = ifelse(LastPurchase < 60, 0, 1),
  LastSale = lag(sales))
```

And here is the result:

```
  store PurchaseDate sales    LastPurchase over60 LastSale
  <chr> <date>       <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   
1 A     2023-01-01   apples              0      0 NA      
2 A     2023-02-01   cherries           31      0 apples  
3 A     2023-04-01   cherries           59      0 cherries
4 A     2023-05-01   bananas            30      0 cherries
5 B     2023-01-01   bananas             0      0 NA      
6 B     2023-03-01   bananas            59      0 bananas 
7 B     2023-04-01   cherries           31      0 bananas 
8 B     2023-06-01   bananas            61      1 cherries
```

Comment: Thanks -- can you explain this line:  mutate(LastPurchase = c(0, diff(PurchaseDate)) ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edited my answer to explain how LastPurchase column is created. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata  %>% 
arrange(store, PurchaseDate) %>% 
group_by(store) %>% 
mutate(Days = difftime(PurchaseDate, lag(PurchaseDate, default = min(mydata$PurchaseDate)), units = 'days'), 
       over60 = if_else(Days <= 60, 0, 1), last_sale = lag(sales))  %>% 
ungroup()
```

Results in

```
  store PurchaseDate sales    Days    over60 last_sale
  <chr> <date>       <chr>    <drtn>   <dbl> <chr>    
1 A     2023-01-01   apples    0 days      0 NA       
2 A     2023-02-01   cherries 31 days      0 apples   
3 A     2023-04-01   cherries 59 days      0 cherries 
4 A     2023-05-01   bananas  30 days      0 cherries 
5 B     2023-01-01   bananas   0 days      0 NA       
6 B     2023-03-01   bananas  59 days      0 bananas  
7 B     2023-04-01   cherries 31 days      0 bananas  
8 B     2023-06-01   bananas  61 days      1 cherries
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to, for the columns returning 1, to pull what was the earlier sale?  So for a 4th column: NA, apples, cherries, cherries, NA, bananas, cherries, bananas?  I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @plover Can you check to see if this is what you want?

Comment: it was close, but it gave an error for the default - I figured it out with the other code provided here, so I appreciate everyone's assistance!